# Overwrite http host header of gRPC client in golang

Tags: go, header, grpc, http2

I sent request by a gRPC client with connection

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("hostname:port",opts...)
```

From server side, I saw the `host` in http.request is the exact `hostname:port`. Then, I have my nginx server settings like

```
server {
    listen port http2;
    server_name hostname;
    # ...
}
server {
    listen port http2;
    server_name another_hostname;
    # ...
}
```

which is a common virtual hosting technique.
It works well no matter which hostname I just use in `grpc.Dial(xxx:port)`. However, when I put

```
md := metadata.New(map[string]string{"host":"another_hostname:port"})
```

in grpc context(which will be filled in the header of http2 request). This request will be blocked by nginx and I got

```
rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 400 (Bad Request); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/html"
```

The reason why I want to put the hostname manually is because the hostname in `grpc.Dial` is fixed. And I cannot use different location to do reverse proxy because after the `port` is the routing path of restful api.

Is there any other way to do reverse proxy if the hostname is fixed and the route is fixed as well?

(23/09)update: It turns out that the host header is supplanted by `:Authority` pseudo header in http2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC uses HTTP/2 and does not use the `:host` header, but instead uses the `:authority` pseudo-header. The value for this header is determined here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/aa6ce35c792863305e0f42acc27f2c7153275f89/clientconn.go#L1942

TL;dr

By default the value used for the `:authority` header is the endpoint portion of the user's dial target which is of the form `url://authority/endpoint`.

gRPC-Go also supports a dial option to override this `authority`. See: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WithAuthority. But also, note that this dial option overrides the `ServerName` value used during the TLS handshake.

If you have more questions/concerns, please feel free to reach us on our GitHub repo. Your queries will see a better response time there.

Comment: Thank you! It precisely solved my problem!